# There's Only 1 Formula To Find The Answer

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, word-search

[image]

*The answer to the puzzle is a seven letter word. May it be yours!*

Comment: Rot13(V'ir sbhaq Naqerggv, Fpuhznpure, Rzrefba, Xrxr, Wnpdhrf, Wrafba naq Obhgfra... Ohg V'z abg fher jung gb qb arkg?)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First we look at the letters

> and find some hidden names
>  [image]

Next we look at

> the title and realize these names might be Formula 1 racers.
>  Sure enough they are and they match the flags on the right so we put them in that order:
>  Jacques Villeneuve, Canada
>  Emerson Fittipaldi, Brazil
>  Michael/Mick Schumacher, Germany
>  Jenson Button, Britain
>  Mario Andretti, USA
>  Keke Rosberg, Finland
>  Thierry Boutsen, Belgium

In some cases

> we were given the last name, in others the first name. If we take the other name and take the nth letter from the nth name we get
>  **V**illeneuve
>  F**I**ttipaldi
>  Mi**C**k
>  But**T**on
>  Mari**O**
>  Rosbe**R**g
>  Thierr**Y**
>  **VICTORY**

Comment: Yay! Wonderful :) Great job.